# Pass parameter from v-for to dynamically update b-tab title

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Only about 6 weeks into using vuejs and haven't looked at components at all, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I am attempting to make the b-spinner component for tabs from [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/) update dynamically inside a v-for loop, with the parameter from the v-for being past to a computed property.

It works fine when not in a v-for.

```
<b-tab>
  <template v-slot:title>
     <b-spinner type="border" small v-show="!updateDone"></b-spinner> <strong>Tab Title</strong>
  </template>
  ...
</b-tab>
```

But when I try to pass the player property from the v-for, it breaks. When I try to pass `player` to the title slot, the entire parent component gets passed.

```
<b-tab :key="player['player-id']" v-for="player in updatePool">
  <template v-slot:title="{player}">
    <b-spinner type="border" small v-show="!updateDone(player)"></b-spinner> <strong>{{player['player-name']}}</strong>
  </template>
  ...
</b-tab>
```

`updateDone` is a computed property as follows:

```
updateDone: function (player) {
  return _.every(Object.values(this.someObject[player['player-name']]), Boolean)
    },
```

But `updateDone` is never returned b/c `player` is an entire Vue object (presumably the parent component)

Hoping for some insight on this.

> SOLUTION
>   Thanks to Antonio

```
<b-tab v-for="player in updatePickPool" :key="player['player-id']">
  <template v-slot:title>
    <b-spinner type="border" small v-show="!playerPathComplete(player)"></b-spinner><strong> {{player['player-name']}}</strong>
  </template>
...
</b-tab>
```

Comment: Did you wrap those `<b-tab>` by `<b-tabs>`?

Comment: indeed I did...

Comment: Is there a unique element such as `id` for each player object?

Comment: Could you show me updateDone method?

Comment: i did not have :key assigned, but this has not solved problem. i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, I realized that `updateDone` is a `computed` property.

Do not use `computed` property in this case.

You have to use `method` instead of `computed` property.

**Why?**
`computed` properties are cached and change only when their dependencies change.
In your case, there's no change in `player` while looping to render tabs. That means it will show the same results of `updateDone` property. :(

But a method will evaluate every time it's called. :)

Comment: thx for answer but that does not seem to work. now when I pass `player` to `updateDone(player)`, it shows `player` is undefined.

Comment: @RyanSkene Please remove `="{player}"` in this code.`<template v-slot:title="{player}">`. so `<template v-slot:title>`

Comment: And what is `someObject`?

Comment: removing `="{player}"` doesn't work. `someObject` is a property of the vue app

Comment: @RyanSkene Please move the `:key` after `v-for`. `player` is undefined before `v-for`

Comment: @RyanSkene If you provide codepen or snippet, then I can help you correctly.